# How to get Coordinates from Google Places API in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, alamofire, mapkitannotation

I am using `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON` to auto complete Google Places. I integrated it well and good like this :

[image]

Now, what I need is if I select a place from the table view, it is selected in the text field. But how can I get the respective latitude and longitude of that place, so that I can add annotation of that place in MapKit

Is it legal to get details from `Google Place API` and display them on apple's MapKit? I got this doubt after seeing Viking's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607538/google-places-api-violation?rq=1)

Comment: First of all, is it possible?

Comment: IIRC you need to make a 2nd query that uses the place ID

Comment: can you please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coordinates from the `GMSPlace` object. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details).

Regarding if you can use google places alongside apple map, no you can't.
As stated in their [Terms of Use](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/usage)

> Make sure that any maps used by your app to show the location of places retrieved from the Google Places API for iOS are **Google maps.**

Comment: That is the thing. I am using Apple Maps along with a text box. In that text box I have added Google AutoComplete Places. So if I dont add annotation for that google place in apple map, will that be okay? Can I use both of them in a single view controller?

Comment: As long as you don't show the results in the map in any way it should be fine. I mean you can show the results in a tableview, but you can never add annotations on the map based on the data.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe i m bit late but stil as a tuttorial i m posting this answer
you can simply get the coordinates like this

```
// Handle the user's selection 

public func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
    var lat = place.coordinate.latitude
    var lon = place.coordinate.longitude
    print("lat lon",lat,lon)

}
```

Comment: Okay where to call this method?

Comment: It's showing same coordinate everytime

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia I got same issue, always getting same coordinates, did you manage solve it?